# Cycles 2.79 Need reflect and refract output

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, render-passes

Blender Render allowed reflection and refraction as distinct output nodes for renders:

[image]

I am working with an FX firm that is asking for the same sort of output from my Cycles render, plus specularity. So reflections, refractions and spec.

My limited knowledge of ray tracers says not literally possible... but can I give them something comparable?

EDIT: Beginnings of an answer for Cycles with multiple render passes, which is not ideal: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2OhybKuHTlM